# How to debug hanging python code when I can't use PDB

Tags: python, debugging, remote-debugging

I have some code that I'm able to run perfectly fine on my local system. Only when I launch it to run automatically as a docker containerized program on a server, does it hang and time out at a particular line. I'm not able to step through the program with pdb in that particular environment, nor can I reproduce the behavior in an environment where I could use a debugger. I can just see in my cloudwatch logs that it's stopping on that line and timing out.

That line of code that is hanging is calling other code, but I don't know internally the exact point where it hangs. Is there any way to wrap something around this line of code that will make it print out every step that it goes through?

(For reference, the actual server is an AWS SageMaker endpoint which is not directly accessible via ssh or anything, and the line of code that is timing out is an AutoGluon `model.predict()` call.)

I guess what I'm looking for could potentially be something like a debug decorator, or a way to automate pdb and wrap it around a function call to see where it's hanging. Or any better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do a sagemaker local session combined with remote pdb. https://pypi.org/project/remote-pdb/ You need the local session so you can easily get inside the container and remote-pdb lets you then connect.